# How to pass LatlngBounds object to nodejs server using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I want to pass a LatlngBounds object from a client to nodejs server.

```
   var bounds = map.getBounds();

   socket.emit('sendbounds', bounds);
```

In the server:

```
 socket.on('sendbounds',function(data){
     console.log(data);
     data.getNorthEast();// undefined method getNorthEast()

  }
```

The server can get the data sent from the client. However I am unable to use method getNorthEast().

My solution is to create an object LatlngBounds:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Ea.k, data.va.j),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(data.Ea.j, data.va.k));
```

However this is not recommended because we cannot sure the key names are always 'Ea' and 'va'. 
 I notice that sometimes the key names are "Fa" and wa". They are "undocumented properties". They change with API releases.

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your client's bounds contain a valid value? In your server, does the console.log() print something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it that way, too, but had the same problem: Can't rely on the variable names.

Instead, I passed it to the server as a string instead of an object:

```
    corners = map.getBounds();
    var c = corners.toString();`
```

Then use whatever AJAX library to send the string to the server. 
It looks something like this:

```
((33.94310833405608, -118.44952616442868), (33.985820303992334, -118.34120783557125))
```

You will have to pick it apart using a regexp, but at least it's reliably formatted.

Comment: You should use .toJSON() instead of .toString() for this

Comment: ...or [.toUrlValue()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng-Methods) ("9.044016,-112.174648,69.879895,100.608555")